# UIViewController - dismissModalViewControllerAnimated issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I'm having an issue with the dismissModalViewControllerAnimated method.

The header looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "GADBannerView.h"
#import "weatherSetUp.h"
@interface weatherPicViewController : UIViewController{
```

In my viewController.m file I call

```
-(IBAction)didClickSetting:(id)sender{
    weatherSetUp *views = [[weatherSetUp alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:views animated:YES];
}
```

This all works fine, In my weatherSetUp file once the user has completed set up I was to dismiss the modal view. I do it by calling this method in the above viewController.m file:

```
-(void)dismissModal{

    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    NSLog(@"Model gone!");
}
```

But none of these work.

This is the header file of my weatherSetUp file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "viewController.h"
@interface weatherSetUp : UIViewController
-(IBAction)didClickClose:(id)sender;
@end
```

And the only method I've implemented is:

```
-(IBAction)didClickClose:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"CLick "); 
    viewController *viewEr = [[viewController alloc] init];
    [viewEr dismissModal];
}
```

All the NSLog's work when I click the button, I've searched on here and tried too the above ways of dismissing it and none of them work, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is going wrong is you're calling dismissModal on a random view controller rather than the object that actually has the modal controller. What you'd want to do in didClickClose: is this

```
[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Also, you shouldn't be starting your class names with lowercase characters in Cocoa. They should really be capitalised and have a prefix, eg ABCWeatherSetUp. The prefix can be whatever you want, but generally you want something based on your name, your company's name or your project's name.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed. I fully understand that now, but I'm still not sure about about this:     viewController *viewEr = [[viewController alloc] init];
    [viewEr dismissModal];

Is it because the actual ViewController with the ModalViewController is already in the heap/stack and creating an instance of my viewController class will just create a new one, by new one I mean a new ViewController that contains no ModalViewControllers?

Comment: Yeah, you were creating a new blank view controller. You needed a reference to the specific instance. In this case UIKit handles this for you, so when you have view controller A which shows view controller B modally, then A is B's parentViewController. In other cases you may need to create this reference yourself (add a property and pass the object to be referenced in).

Answer (score 0):

Your viewEr is not the same viewController which you are trying to close, because you are creating the new object of your viewContoller.

you can create a viewContoller properties and in your viewController class file

```
weatherSetup.viewController = self.parentViewController;
```

NOTE: do not use viewContoller as a ivar, use different may name.

Answer (score 0):

insted of  `[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];`
write this  `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];`